# Jquery get only the class target of an event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to get the class that firing the alert

The problem is that all the class of the `<i>` will be alert on the

`trigger('click')`, I just want to get the class used

Here a example with the class `main`

Html

```
<i class="main mainBack another another2 another3"></i>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).on('click','.main, .mainBack', function(e) {
   alert(e.target.className);
});

$('.main').trigger('click');
```

Jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/474x5ew5/1/

Comment: What do you want to do with the class name? Can't you approach it the opposite way and test if the clicked element has the class you care about? `if ($(this).hasClass("main")) { /* do something */ }`.

Comment: You should pass it to event data when calling trigger method, check documentation but sounds like a XY problem, why would you need this behaviour?

Comment: No I need to know the exact class that firing for some other part of the code that require different action (if this class then or if this class...)

Comment: So it is a XY problem,  thats not the way to do that, you should use namespaced events instead https://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Event handlers are bound to elements not to their `className`s so `e.target.className` returns all the classNames of the element.

Since you are using `trigger` method you can pass custom data to the handler:

```
$(document).on('click','.main, .mainBack', function(e, data) {
     if (data === 'main') {
       // ...
     }
});

$('.main').trigger('click', ['main']);
```

Using the above snippet when the event is triggered manually the second argument of the handler is `main`.

Another option is using jQuery `.hasClass()` method for checking existence of a certain class name.

```
if ( $(this).hasClass('main') ) {
   // ...
}
```

Comment: hasClass is not the solution of my problem, the html <i> has the class. I want to know which class was selected with a trigger (many other on the code using other class as mainBack or another2...). However the passing data is magic.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I think you should be adding attributes to the click target:

```
<i class="main mainBack another another2 another3" data-action="DoSomething"></i>
<i class="main mainBack another another2 another3" data-action="DoSomethingElse"></i>
```

then in your JavaScript:

```
$(document).on('click','.main, .mainBack', function(e) {
    if (e.target.attr("data-action") == "DoSomething") {
        ...
    } else if (...) 
});
```

Comment: I guess an element can fire more than just one action

Comment: Well then remove the `else` ... and add another action. Classes are for styling and targeting not determining action states.

Comment: Ya classes shouldnt bring data but this has nothing to do with OP question